# Add Road IDs to Parcel Layer (Or Parcel IDs to road layer)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3

I am trying to create a table that links a road segment with all the parcels that would be "touching" that road. 
A road has an average of about 10 parcels, but most parcels would only be on one road. However, a parcel on a corner would be "touching" 2 road segments and a rural parcel may actually be on 3 road segments (front, back and one side). 
My road is a road centreline, so they don't overlap, but a 15-20m buffer would be perfect, I just don't know how to add\join the fields after that. It doesn't matter whether the road id is added to the parcel or the parcel ID is added to the road, in the end I just want a table with both IDs.

I am using ArcGIS 10.3.1

[image]

For the example above, the table I want would be:

**P   R**
1          A
2          A
3          A
4          A
4          B
5          A
6          A
7          A
8          A
8          B

Comment: As you say, it's possible and likely you'll have one parcel with multiple road matches. How do you want to handle that situation? Pick one road, any road? A specific one (ie longest or shortest frontage)? Include all the combinations in the result (and if so, as single rows for either road segment or parcel, and if single rows, matches as independent attributes or a single field with a list)?

Comment: I updated an example to show exactly what I am looking for, sorry for not being clear enough!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use a [spatial join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000000q000000):

Target features: your parcel layer

Join features: your roads layer

Join operation: JOIN_ONE_TO_MANY

check "Keep All Target Features"

You can control which fields will end up in the Output Feature Class in the "Field Map of Join Features" dialog box.

Match option: WITHIN_A_DISTANCE

Search radius: 20 (assuming your feature class projection is using meters)

Spatial joins can take a long time depending on how many features you have in each class. I would run on a small portion of your data first to test it out.

Comment: I don't think you want a one-to-many here. That would duplicate each parcel once for every road segment within the search radius (or vice versa if you swap target/join features). If you want to ensure *every* road/parcel combination in the search radius is met, sure. Regardless you're likely to have a many-to-many join situation here, and that option would create a table that needs work/flattening. If you just do one-to-one, it will simply pick a single road segment (no control over which) to assign to the parcel and ignore the rest.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. For some reason I forgot this was also a tool, and I was only doing a spatial join by right clicking the layer and looking under join. If you do it that way it doesn't give you any options. Thanks jmcbroom!

Comment: @sunburstali Right-click layer just gets you access to a regular or table join, not spatial. They're two different kinds of join (attributes vs geometry), and the spatial is only a tool. If you just want the table and don't mind the duplicate records, it'll absolutely work and is a quick method. I just wasn't clear from your original question if you only cared about getting the relationships or you wanted a new attribute on either dataset and still be able to use them (because duplicating records can lead to issues with further geometry-based operations).

Comment: @sunburstali Actually now I feel sheepish, because part of what I said above is incorret. You *can* do a spatial join from a right-click. As you say, it just doesn't give you full control/the same options as the tool version.